# Perl simple regex capture group not capturing

Tags: regex, perl

For the sake of data entry, I have a hash of variable size, with multiple elements having similar names. An example of what the hash might look like would be;

- wineName0 => Chardonnay
- wineFull0 => 4.00
- wineHalf0 => 2.00
- wineName1 => Pinot Noir
- wineFull1 => 16.00
- wineHalf1 => 8.00
- plateName0 => Flank Steak
- plateCost0 => 14.00
- plateTemps0 => allow

As for processing them, I am iterating through the keys, checking them with a regex, capturing their number, then using that number to grab similarly numbered elements, like so;

```
        foreach $key (sort keys %in){
            if($key =~ /wineName(\d+)/){
                if($wineTable eq ""){
                    $wineTable = qq{
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 class="label">Wines</td>
        </tr>
                    };
                }
                $wineName = $key;
                    $in{$wineName} =~ s/\s/+/g;
                $wineFull = "wineFull$1";
                $wineHalf = "wineHalf$1";

                $wineTable .= qq{
        <tr>
            <!-- $key -->
            <td>$in{$wineName}</td>
            <td>\$$in{$wineFull}</td>
            <td>\$$in{$wineHalf}</td>
        </tr>
                };
            }
            if($key =~ /beerName(\d+)/){
                if($beerTable eq ""){
                    $beerTable = qq{
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 class="label">Beers</td>
        </tr>
                    };
                }
                $beerName = $key;
                    $in{$beerName} =~ s/\s/+/g;
                $beerFull = "beerFull$1";
                $beerHalf = "beerHalf$1";

                $beerTable .= qq{
        <tr>
            <!-- $key -->
            <td>$in{$beerName}</td>
            <td>\$$in{$beerFull}</td>
            <td>\$$in{$beerHalf}</td>
        </tr>
                };
            }
            if($key =~ /plateName(\d+)/){
                if($plateTable eq ""){
                    $plateTable = qq{
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Cook Temperatures</th>
        </tr>
                    };
                }
                my $plateName = $key;
                    $in{$plateName} =~ s/\s/+/g;
                my $plateCost = "plateCost$1";
                my $plateTemp = "plateTemps$1";

                if($in{$plateTemp}){
                    $in{$plateTemp} = 1;
                }else{
                    $in{$plateTemp} = 0;
                }

                $plateTable .= qq{
        <tr>
            <!-- $key -->
            <td>$in{$plateName}</td>
            <td>\$$in{$plateCost}</td>
            <td>$in{$plateTemp}</td>
        </tr>
                };
            }
        }
```

My problem is that for some reason, `/plateName(\d+)/` is not capturing. so if `$key == "plateName1"`, `$plateCost` ends up equaling "plateCost", and not "plateCost1." The hash keys I've given as examples are actual examples. With this in mind, I need help understanding why the regex for wines works, while the regex for plates does not work, considering they are nearly identical.

Comment: Can you share your specific regex and data for the case it isn't working?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza The regex and data shown are exactly what I'm using.

Comment: What output do you expect? It seems to work for me, it just doesn't populate wines and plates in the same iteration of the loop, as it processes just one key in each step.

Comment: regex is working properly for me.  I suspect you just need to throw debugging lines in, something else is wrong like your hash may be PlateName and not plateName, perl is case sensitive.

Comment: @choroba I added an expected versus actual output to the question

Comment: There are serious issues with how this is supposed to be used. What do you want to do with `$string`? Half of it is uninitialized in each iteration, since only either wines or plates are set, never both.  You should probably edit the question to show enough of the context.

Comment: Alright, removing that comment -- and editing the one after it.  Please read it over in a few seconds.

Comment: @zdim I was looking to avoid a wall of text, but I've updated it for the literal code, not just a condensed version. [Here's the actual output](https://jsfiddle.net/hquop1ad/1/).

Comment: I going to delete the question in a day or two, as I figured out the problem. If `$in{$[wine|beer|plate]Name}` had any whitespace in it, I would replace them with a '+'. This seems to then be overwriting $1, thus making the other keys useless. Lesson learned.

Comment: Good catch, that substitution wipes out `$1`.  Another lesson, perhaps: too complicated? (For one, must you write HTML by hand?)  Only musing here, I don't know your problem and this may well be most suitable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your posted code, it looks like the problem is with:

```
$in{$plateName} =~ s/\s/+/g;
```

where you have too many `/` in the pattern?